# Concurrency in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

Assume you have the following code in a Play web application:

```
class MyClass extends Controller  {

  def myMethod = Action {

      var a = 0

      while ( a < 1000 ) {
         println( "Value of a: " + a );
         a = a + 1;
      }

  }

}
```

Could I have a race condition if two users/browsers invoke the same method? If yes, how to avoid it?

Comment: In this case the variable `a` is local to thread that executes the `Action`'s `Future`, so the answer is **no**. If the `a` was declared as the *field* of controller then, of course, it would have race condition. Another way to introduce problems is making more `Future`s/`Thread`s/`Actors` involved in changing `a`.

Comment: @insan-e but that's only applicable if the controller is a singleton. If it's created per-request instead, then there should be no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`a` is created per request.

Also check out action async if you're returning Futures.

Answer (score 2):

This will always print `Value of a: 0`, because `a` is a local variable and you're initializing it with `0` on each request.

If you declared it outside the scope of your method, then it could work as a counter (if your controller is a singleton), but yes, you would have potential race conditions.

One way to resolve it is to use a singleton instance of an `AtomicInteger` in your controller. You can see more details on that here: https://github.com/zoltanmaric/slike/blob/master/app/controllers/CountController.scala

Comment: While this would probably technically work, I would not recommend/advise such things to beginners. Especially if we're talking about an inherently stateless framework here (at least that's the aim).

Comment: @rethab I completely agree with you

Comment: why are you saying `you're initializing it with 0 on each request` if I'm incrementing `a` in the loop?

Comment: @ps0604 actually I just realized my answer was completely wrong. Rhys Bradbury was right. There is no race condition. You create a local variable `a` for each request and count it up to `1000`. That's perfectly fine. I assumed you were trying to count the number of requests to your controller, which is why I suggested using the `CountController`.